# Unexplained IncompatibleClassChangeError In Stable Released App Caused by GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have just received this strange crash report from a user in my Google Play Developer Console.

The app is stable at the moment and this is the first time I have seen this crash. It has been in release for 3/4 months now. The device was a Galaxy S5 running Android Version 5.0.

My initial thoughts is Google Play Services has updated causing issues. Any better offers?

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' does not implement interface 'android.os.Parcelable$Creator' in call to 'java.lang.Object android.os.Parcelable$Creator.createFromParcel(android.os.Parcel)' (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelReader.createParcelable(SafeParcelReader.java:227)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptionsCreator.createFromParcel(GoogleMapOptionsCreator.java:93)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ICreator$Stub.onTransact(ICreator.java:74)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.a(SourceFile:204)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(SourceFile:110)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:79)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.am.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.l.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.c.d.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.Activity.onStart(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6258)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

**ADDITION** Have just found [this thread](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=283740&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~) which is about other people experiencing the same crash on Samsung devices.

Comment: I think you can report a `google map` bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Android2%20type:Defect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars), but it a `Samsung` related, you can also go to `Samsung` support or the forum [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/394154-google-maps-note-3-issues.html).

Answer (score 1):

This was related to [issue 8314](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8314).  This issue has now been fixed via both a Firmware update from Samsung and also an update to Google Play Services.