# Android Google Maps api v2 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android

In the last 3 weeks I keep getting a crash on my app in Developer Console. It happens on startup, on Galaxy S5 (kite) with Android 5.0. And the exception is:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.android.gms.a.b implements non-interface class com.google.android.gms.a.a (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.a.b' appears in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/chimera-module-root/module-dd5b1d6850a09abe29b143730d133d3d1f4c4971/MapsModule.apk)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:240)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:233)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:104)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.a(SourceFile:256)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(SourceFile:82)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:96)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.a.al.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.q.g(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.q.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.n.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(SourceFile:1766)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:917)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1501)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:551)
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: try this code ....
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  if(mapView != null)
   mapView.onDestroy();
 }

Comment: hmm, the thing is that it happens in onStart method from the first run so this would not resolve the crash.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, but with this stack: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' does not implement interface 'android.os.Parcelable$Creator' in call to 'java.lang.Object android.os.Parcelable$Creator.createFromParcel(android.os.Parcel)' (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar) and it's Samsung problem check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969599/unexplained-incompatibleclasschangeerror-in-stable-released-app-caused-by-google